# JSF 2 + Primefaces: Need to update bean property on menu click before rendering dialog

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a p:menuitem that needs to (1) update a backing bean property when clicked, and then (2) show a p:dialog.

This is the set up I have:

```
<p:menuitem value="Show Dialog"
            oncomplete="dialog_widget.show();"
            update=":dialog"
            actionListener="#{bean.setCurrentAction}">
</p:menuitem>

<p:dialog widgetVar="dialog_widget" id="dialog" dynamic="true">
     <h:form>
        <p:inputText value="#{bean.record.text} />
     // the proper rendering of this dialog form depends on bean.currentAction
     // being set during JSF Phase 4 Update Model Values

</p:dialog>
```

And the backing bean:

```
public R getRecord() {
    if (currentAction == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return currentAction == NEW ? newRecord : selectedRecord;
}
```

The problem is that actionListeners and actions are only executed during Phase 5 and I need the bean.currentAction to be set before that so the dialog can be properly updated and rendered.

** A little background on what I'm trying to achieve: the dialog form is used to Create new records as well as Update exsiting records (Add and Edit Dialog). So the "currentAction" on the bean indicates which action the user is doing. Depending on which action, the form needs to use different model objects ("newRecord" or "selectedRecord") to pull and save the form data to.

Comment: What's the scope of your bean?

Comment: The backing bean is ViewScoped

Comment: Actually I'm quite puzzled as to why the form has to go through Apply Request Values, Process Validations and Update Model Values. The dialog form is displaying for the first time, there is nothing to apply and validate. I assumed that the #{controller.record} would only be resolved during RenderResponse. So that being said, I worked around this by adding partialSubmit="true" and process="@this ..and in my case the table_id" to limit the scope of processing. But I'd like to know if there is a better approach.

Comment: The dialog is but just a component in the entire view. The entire view is put thru the paces of the lifecycle

Comment: So in an app where we might have many (hidden) dialogs and buttons to show the dialogs in one page, what is the best way to limit processing of the entire ViewRoot when a user clicks on only one button to perform one action? Is the approach I'm using the "accepted" way, it just seems a little hard to maintain...

Comment: Wait, is there an enclosing form around the menu and the dialog?

Comment: There is a form around the menuitem, but not around the dialog.

Comment: As a workaround, Add a `preValidate` event listener to the menuItem and do the preliminary processing there. Barring any other interference, your variable should be ready for display in the popup

Answer (score 0):

Although not a very elegant solution you can use PrimeFaces' RequestContext's update method to set update target and use the execute method to show your dialog in your actionListener after setting the needed property.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it out. However I would really like to avoid hard-coding UI ids etc in the backing bean... This seems to be a common scenario so I'm going to see if there are other approaches.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. The dialog shows up but the form fields do not contain any data even though they should.

Answer (score 0):

If you requirement is to call the backing bean method before the dialog opens then you can go for a ajax function (i don't know whether you are allowed to use ajax in your application). for p:menuItem there is a function called **onclick**, where you can call a **a4j:ajax** function through which you can call a backing bean method and update the model before dialog opens.

Comment: OP's clearly stated he's using Primefaces. Update or remove your answer please

Comment: I thought about that, but even if this approach translates to an equivalent in PF, would this be a race condition -- unreliable?

Answer (score 0):

By default action is called during "Invoke Application" phase. You can add `immediate="true"` attribute in `p:menuitem` tag. This will call action in "Apply Request Values" phase.

Comment: I tried that too, but I can't bypass Update Model Values completely because my dialog may display data based on a datatable selection (use case not shown in my original question).